# Change the text on a button in the program

Tags: android, button

The text on my buttons are set in resource files. E.g.

```
            <Button android:id="@+id/up_button" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/up_label" />
```

The above code defines a button with text `@string/up_label`. How can I change this text in my program during the application is running.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up_button);
myButton.setText("my text");
```

maybe this will help.

Answer (score 6):

Or, if you have the new text in resources (which I think you do), you do

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up_button);
myButton.setText(R.string.down_label);
```

where `down_label` is the id of your string.

Answer (score 1):

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up_button);

For example:

```
button.setText("This is how to change text at runtime");
```